Конспектирование в телеграмм боте
У меня есть чат-бот с ии, помощник с домашним заданием, и есть кнопка "Сделай конспект", после этого бот отвечает "Отправьте текст", но дело в том что после этого я могу вводить любые запросы нейросети, и конспект будет только в том случае если я перед текстом напишу "законспектируй" и т.п. Как сделать так чтобы я отправил текст и бот выдавал уже готовый конспект?
import os
from telebot import types

waiting_for_summary = False

bot = telebot.TeleBot('7126215030:AAHxlTWQIJSsqwg_3G8SoPBu70l4HL96tqM')


def generate_text(text):

    url = "https://api.edenai.run/v2/text/chat"
    payload = {
        "providers": "openai",
        "text": text,
        "response_as_dict": True,
        "attributes_as_list": False,
        "show_original_response": False,
        "temperature": 0,
        "max_tokens": 1000
    }
    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": "Bearer " + os.environ["API_KEY"]
    }

    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    start = response.text.find("generated_text") + 17
    end = response.text.find("message") - 3

    return response.text[start:end]



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)

    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, " Привет! Я твой бот-помошник!", reply_markup=markup)

    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Спросить у помощника")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Создать задачу')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)

    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Выбери режим бота", reply_markup=markup)





@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    global waiting_for_summary

    if waiting_for_summary:
        summary = generate_text(message.text)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, summary)
        waiting_for_summary = False
    else:
        if message.text == ' Поздороваться':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)  # создание новых кнопок
            btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Как стать автором на Хабре?')
            btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Правила сайта')
            btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Советы по оформлению публикации')
            markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '❓ Задайте интересующий вас вопрос', reply_markup=markup)  # ответ бота

        elif message.text == 'Спросить у помощника':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Объясни')
            btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Подбери материалы')
            btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Ответь на вопросы по коду')
            btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Сделай конспект')

            markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Как я могу тебе помочь?', reply_markup=markup)  # ответ бота

        elif message.text == 'Создать задачу':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введи название задачи', reply_markup=markup)  # ответ бота

        elif message.text == 'Сделай конспект':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Отправь текст для которого требуется сделать конспект', reply_markup=markup)
            waiting_for_summary = True
        elif message.text == 'Объясни':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            bot.send_message(message.fro)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)  # обязательная для работы бота часть


"text": "законспектируй " + text,

и как я не догадался, спасибо!
